# eclipse: Surround block with if

Tags: java, eclipse

In eclipse we can surround a piece of code with try/catch. I want to surround a piece of code with if statement. Is there any shortcut key. Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> after selecting the block of code did not give me hint to surround with `If`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Highlight the block of code , press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, then choose if (3).

Answer (score 3):

In Eclipse Galileo

1. Select the code and right click on it
2. Select the `Surround with` option from the context menu
3. Choose `if statement`.